# htaccess rules for website are not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, magento

I have website where on root i have htacess files and two folder for (`blog->WP,shop->Magento)`.
My directory structure are like this `root (htaccess,other files,blog,shop)`.this was my htaccess code on root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

It works with these url's like `example.com and example.com/blog ->for WP and example.com/shop-> for Magento`.But now i transferred to new domain and convert site to ip base.I want to access my site like `192.168.2.36`.If i change above htaccess code with ip it only works for home, for inner it gives errors.Please help how can i solve the issue.I want to access my site like `IP/blog,IP/shop`

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```